# Create a DateTimeOffset set to Midnight in a different TimeZone from server

Tags: .net, datetimeoffset

I have a server set to EST and am wondering what I need to do to create a DateTimeOffset set to Midnight of the current day but in a different timezone? For example PST?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Fetch the relevant `TimeZoneInfo`.
- Construct a `DateTime` which contains the *local* time (i.e. midnight)
- Call [`TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396378.aspx) to find the offset from UTC
- Construct a `DateTimeOffset` with the local time and the offset

(If [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) were production-ready, I'd suggest creating a `ZonedDateTime` using that, but unfortunately we're not even close to ready for v1 yet... although actually the bits you'd need are probably stable enough :)

It's worth noting that "midnight of the current day" doesn't always exist in all time zones. If you may need to deal with time zones which have a DST transition at midnight, you may want to look at [`TimeZoneInfo.IsAmbiguousTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396403.aspx) and [`TimeZoneInfo.IsInvalidTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.isinvalidtime.aspx).

Comment: Interesting.  Can you give an example of a timezone that skips over midnight during a transition?  While it's possible, I assumed (probably incorrectly) that this didn't happen in the real world.

Comment: I found one.  Brazil. DateTime.Date - Crash! OUCH!

Comment: @MattJohnson: Yup, Brazil's the one I'm aware of. There may be other ones too.