# Determine the number of hours between two DateTimes in a specific Time Zone, taking DST into account

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimeoffset

I'm trying to write a function that will (1) run on a machine in any time zone, (2) calculate the number of hours between two dates, and (3) take DST settings for the given time zone into account...

It seems so easy, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm generating work schedules in other time zones.  So, yesterday (Nov. 6th, 2016) in New York, for example, I would need to generate 25 hours worth of schedules.  Today (Nov. 7th, 2016) I would only need to generate schedules for 24 hours.  Next March, there will be a day that requires 23 hours.

I was looking at this being my signature, but I think I might need a `string TimeZoneId` argument.

```
public double GetScheduledHours(DateTime begin, DateTime end) {}
```

I started here:

```
// incorrectly outputs 24
Console.WriteLine((new DateTime(2016, 11, 7) - new DateTime(2016, 11, 6)).TotalHours);
```

I tried this next, with short-lived success:

```
// correctly outputs 25 on a machine whose local time zone is "Eastern Standard Time"
// incorrectly outputs 24 on dotnetfiddle whose local time zone is "Coordinated Universal Time"
var ticks = (new DateTime(2016, 11, 7).ToUniversalTime().Ticks - new DateTime(2016, 11, 6).ToUniversalTime().Ticks;
Console.WriteLine(ticks / 10000 / 1000 / 60 / 60 + " hours");
```

I tried using DateTimeOffset to no avail and found some odd behavior as well...

```
// on a machine whose local time zone is Easter Standard Time,
// if you store the DateTime inside of a DateTimeOffset, simple subtraction works fine
var pacificTz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");

DateTime pst6thAsDateTime = pst6th.DateTime;
DateTime pst7thAsDateTime = pst7th.DateTime;

DateTimeOffset pst6thAsDateTimeOffset = pst6th.DateTime;
DateTimeOffset pst7thAsDateTimeOffset = pst7th.DateTime;

// incorrectly outputs 24
Console.WriteLine((pst7thAsDateTime - pst6thAsDateTime).TotalHours);

// correctly outputs 25
// also incorrectly outputs 24 on a machine whose local time zone is not "Eastern Standard Time"
Console.WriteLine((pst7thAsDateTimeOffset - pst6thAsDateTimeOffset).TotalHours);
```

A fiddle with some codes... if you run this code on a machine whose local time zone is "Eastern Standard Time", only 2 fail.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/djZ7ME

Comment: You also have to keep in mind in NY changes the DST at 6th November, but in Europe at 30th October.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to use the local time zone of the machine, then the answer is very simple:

```
var start = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2016, 11, 6));
var end = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime( 2016, 11, 7));
var hours = (end - start).TotalHours; // 25
```

However, if the timezone you are interested in is not the local one, things get a little more complicated. [Jon Skeet's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668390/create-a-datetimeoffset-set-to-midnight-in-a-different-timezone-from-server) shows the solution to finding midnight in a specific timezone which should help.

```
var pacificTz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
var startLocal = new DateTime(2016, 11, 6);
var startOffset = new DateTimeOffset(startLocal, pacificTz.GetUtcOffset(startLocal));
var endLocal = new DateTime(2016, 11, 7);
var endOffset = new DateTimeOffset(endLocal, pacificTz.GetUtcOffset(endLocal));
var hours = (endOffset - startOffset).TotalHours; // 25
```

In this case, as the reference answer points out, you should take care of creating times that do not exist!

Answer (score -1):

you can use [IsDaylightSavingTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.isdaylightsavingtime(v=vs.110).aspx) and use XOR operation to add or subtract an hour. In my test I'm using german time zone to test. Maybe you have to adapt the testdates. I'm using [fluentassertions](http://www.fluentassertions.com/) to assert.

```
[TestFixture]
public class DateTimeScheduleTests
{
    public double GetScheduledHours(DateTime begin, DateTime end)
    {
        var beginIsDaylight = begin.IsDaylightSavingTime();
        var endIsDayLight = end.IsDaylightSavingTime();

        var diff = 0;
        if (beginIsDaylight ^ endIsDayLight)
            diff = beginIsDaylight ? -1 : 1;

        return (begin - end).TotalHours + diff;
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestDate()
    {
        var begin = new DateTime(2016, 10, 30);
        var end = new DateTime(2016, 10, 29);

        GetScheduledHours(begin, end).Should().Be(24);

        begin = new DateTime(2016, 10, 31);
        end = new DateTime(2016, 10, 30);

        GetScheduledHours(begin, end).Should().Be(25);

        begin = new DateTime(2017, 3, 26);
        end = new DateTime(2017, 3, 25);

        GetScheduledHours(begin, end).Should().Be(24);

        begin = new DateTime(2017, 3, 27);
        end = new DateTime(2017, 3, 26);

        GetScheduledHours(begin, end).Should().Be(23);
    }
}
```

Comment: `DateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime` will only tell you if the value provided is in DST *for the current local time zone* - not for a given named time zone.

Comment: But as I understand the question from @Langdon he is just interested in the current local time zone
`(1) run on a machine in any time zone,`
`(3) take DST settings for the given time zone into account`

Comment: Right, `"for the given time zone"` - regardless of the one set on the machine.  The title also says `"in a specific time zone"`.

Comment: Also, your answer makes some assumptions: 1) that the DST bias is always one hour, and 2) that there is no change in standard offset between the begin and end dates.  Both of these can be proven false in certain edge cases.  The accepted answer uses the framework methods that account for this properly.